# How do I Pass Multiple Selected Datagrid Values to Another Page in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, datagrid

I have multiple asp.net data grids that a user can select a checkbox to the corresponding value that they want, put in the amount they want in a textbox and submit the request. How do I show what values they requested with the amount on the next page? I can do this with a session I believe but I'm having a hard time finding good examples for something like this. Since they can select multiple values I can't use a query string right? I'm using VB.net but if you answer in c# that's fine. Thanks!

```
<asp:GridView ID="flexGridView" DataKeyNames="ID" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="FormSqlDataSource" CssClass="gridView" ClientIDMode="Static">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="flexCheckBoxList" runat="server" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Form" ShowHeader="False" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ID" HeaderText="ID" InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="ID" Visible="False" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Category" HeaderText="Category" SortExpression="Category" ShowHeader="False" Visible="False" />
        <asp:TemplateField Visible="false">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblEmail" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Email")%>' />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Qty" >
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="flexTextBox" runat="server" Width="40" ></asp:TextBox>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Session` or query string, but I would recommend `Session`, as there are limitations on the length of a query string, especially if you are not sure how many check boxes might be checked.

Use the `OnCheckChanged` event of the check box control and set `AutoPostBack` to true in your template field, like this:

```
<asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:CheckBox ID="flexCheckBoxList" runat="server" 
                      AutoPostBack="True" OnCheckedChanged="Check_Clicked" />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>

protected void Check_Clicked(Object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    // Store the check box name, ID or whatever unique value you want in Session here
    CheckBox theCheckBox = sender as CheckBox;

    // Was the check box found?
    if(theCheckBox != null)
    {
        // Store in Session
        Session["CheckBoxValue"] = theCheckBox.SomePropertyValue;
    }
}
```

Then in the `Page_Load` of your redirect page, you will need to read out the `Session` value for the checked check boxes.